# using different params with the jqGrid api for paging

Tags: jquery, api, rest, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with a restful api. By default when I click "next page", I get a url like:

```
http://myservice.com?rows=20&page=2
```

(I'm leaving out some params to keep the example simple.)

The service expects a url like:

```
http://myservice.com?limit=20&offset=2
```

What's the easiest way to set up that translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the `prmNames` option. See the [options documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions).

Comment: That's terrific, thanks. Related question: the service has an offset parameter (i.e. the number of records to skip), while this has a page param. Is there a way for me to make /that/ translation?

Comment: You might be able to do it in `beforeRequest`: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Comment: yeah, I was thinking it would be something like that. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: thanks for the link.  Why is the the jqGrid wiki not easier to navigate?  I'm new to jqGrid (my team is recommending it to me) and so far, I've had much better luck with links provided by other to the docs vs. links and structure provided by whomever is moderating (the site/wiki/source code).  +1 for the answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

If your service has different parameters for pagination and sorting then you can manipulate the request URL in `beforeRequest` event. I had to do this since my service accepts `startIndex` and `recordCount`.

```
beforeRequest: function() {
    var postData = $('#mygrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
    // add your pagination and sorting parameters here
    postData.startIndex = postData.page * postData.rows - postData.rows;
    postData.recordCount = postData.rows;
    // delete parameters that you don't need
    delete postData.page;
}
```

In the above code postData has query string parameters which get appended to the URL in case of GET request. If you have POST request containing JSON body then you can handle that too.